# JavaScript find element between

Tags: javascript, events

I'm looking for the most brilliant idea. The focus is **Efficiency** - let's try to avoid a bunch of loops =)

No libraries. This is an exercise in pure JS genius. Feel free to reference functions from inside a library though, if they accomplish this. No need for fallbacks to crappy old browsers (ie: IE).

**The Setup**

I am trying to create event delegation. I am binding an event listener to a container element (the context) for each event type that happens within this element (click, mouseenter, etc.). The listener references a function, we'll call the "route".

There's an object, created separately that looks something like this (example):

```
myarr['click']['.myclass'] = functionReference1;
myarr['click']['#myid'] = functionReference2;
myarr['click']['div>a'] = functionReference3;
```

The `route` takes `event.type` (here, 'click') and goes to myarr and gets all the `click` records. `route` then loops through each *selector key* and matches it against the `event.target`. If it matches, the function reference is called, the `callback` if you will.

This is all well and good. Fairly quick, straightforward.

**The Question**

The `event.target` may be a child of an element that matches the *selector key*. I'm looking for the crazy smooth voodoo black magic to determine if that parent is between our context element and `event.target`. Preferably, some native browser function.

IDEALLY, as example, I could do something along the lines of

`context.querySelectorAll(key + " " + event.target);`

but obviously, I can't pass an object into querySelectorAll, as far as I know.

**What's Been Tried**

Two methods have been tried. Both WORK. Neither is pretty.

**1)**

Loop through the event.target.parentNode until a match is found. This totes does it, but it creates a loop inside my existing loop. Starts getting SLOW when there's several selector keys and lots of elements on the page.

```
if (event['target'].matchesSelector(key)) {
    //do callback
} else {
    var et = event['target'];
    while (et['parentNode'] !== null and et['parentNode'] !== this) {
        et = et['parentNode'];
        if (et.matchesSelector(key)) {
            //do callback
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**2)**

Use ranges. I'm rather proud of this one, but it has the same multi-loop problem. Haven't tested performance too heavily, but there's MANY things that happen here, and if there's a LOT of elements matching the selector key, this is probably going to hurt efficiency.

```
if (event['target'].matchesSelector(key)){
    //do callback
} else {
    var range2 = document.createRange();
    range2.selectNode(event.target);
    var range = document.createRange();         
    var allthese = document.querySelectorAll(key)
    for (var i = 0; i < allthese.length; i++){
        range.selectNode(allthese[i]);
        if (range2.compareBoundaryPoints(range2.START_TO_START, range) && range2.compareBoundaryPoints(range2.END_TO_END, range) <= 0){
            //do callback
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**MAGIC VOODOO** - find me some, and I'll create a big bounty when I have the rep again.

Comment: Do you need the selector keys to stay as strings, or can they be resolved up front to the nodes they select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should try this:

```
event['target'].matchesSelector(key) || event['target'].matchesSelector(key + ' *')
```

Here my second condition will check if the target is Descendant of the key selector

As you can see in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pHSWK/1/)(fiddle Works in webkit(prefer chrome) browsers only) the child/Descendant is matched using parent selector

PS: This method would not work if you also need that element which matches the actual key, but in your question as you said "crazy smooth voodoo black magic to determine if that parent is between our context element and event.target", so I suppose you don't need the actual element

Comment: This is brilliant. And you are correct, but i can always use a slow loop method if it does match.

Comment: No problem! This is the most efficient way I've found to do this, and it's helped me a lot!

Comment: I just wanted to say, after all this time, I had call to use this once again.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
        if (event['target'].matchesSelector(key)) {
           //do callback
         } else {
            var allthese = document.querySelectorAll(key) //this array has order
           //use  "binary search" here to improve perfomance.
            for (var i = 0; i < allthese.length; i++){
                if(event['target'].compareDocumentPosition(allthese[i])&&DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS){
                    //do callback
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

You can use a Algorithm like **binary search**,to improve performance(allthese is a **ordered** array).

The return value of compareDocumentPosition is:

- DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED    1
- **DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING**   2
- **DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING**   4
- DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS    8
- DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY    16
- DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC     32

so,you can search that array "document.querySelectorAll(key)" with a search algorithm.